# wordpress dynamic content for dynamic pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress for my next CMS project. Say I have a page template (full width page template) but the pages under that template have certain parts that are in one page but not in another . I am not talking about the content, the content comes from wordpress. I am talking about some specific parts of pages (say some images) which may be in one page but not in another . However the pages are under the same template.

I could accomplish it by creating separate templates for every such page, but that wont be appropriate.

In my last template, I used the ID of the current page/post to hide and display such contents for those particular pages/posts, But when the page is deleted and added again, all of my code would be meaningless because my code couldnot match the new ID.

I was thinking about doing it by matching the name of the page instead of ID, but when I use `the_title()` to compare, it displays the title because the nature of `the_title()` function is to display the title. How can I use it to compare the title?

```
if(the_title() == "home"){
   //show the content for home page
}
```

Is there any other appropriate way to accomplish the thing that I want ??

Comment: for future reference / use, there is also a WordPress specific Stack Exchange site at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead:

```
if (get_the_title() == "home") {
   //show the content for home page
}
```

Comment: is it ok to use this ? I mean is there any better alternative to it that you know??